# Elementwise division, disregarding zeros

Tags: python, numpy

It's a python question: let's say I have an `m+1`-dimensional numpy array `a` consisting of non-negative numbers, and I would like to obtain an array `b` of the same size where the last coordinates are normalized so that they sum up to 1, or zero in case all of them were zeros. For example, if `m = 2`, my code would be as follows

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[ 0.34      ,  0.66],
               [ 0.75      ,  0.25]],
              [[ 0.        ,  0.  ],
               [ 1.        ,  0.  ]]])

for i1 in range(len(a)):
    for i2 in range(len(a)):
        s = a[i1][i2].sum()
        if s > 0:
            a[i1][i2] = a[i1][i2]/s
```

however I find this method sloppy. Also, it works only for fixed `m`.

Comment: Instead of describing your data, it's better to give example data as runnable Python code.

Comment: @MrE: thanks for suggestion, but for a high-dimensional array I can't really think of a way how to compactly put that in the OP.

Comment: Just write down a small array with the same properties, something like `np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]])`. A lot of the time, maybe not this time, people trying to help you will misinterpret the question because the description was ambiguous.

Comment: @MrE: I see, like in the edit?

Comment: Pretty much. I edited your question a bit more so that it can be run exactly as written (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MrE: thanks, I'll check that out. Do I really have to wait 90 minutes before asking the next question?

Comment: best look into that on meta, e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941/553404 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/160939 . Looks like you need a few more rep points before you can post more frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by broadcasting. There are several ways to take into account the zero-sum exception. Without taking it into account, you could write

```
import numpy as np
shape = (2, 3, 4)
X = np.random.randn(*shape) ** 2
sums = X.sum(-1)

Y = X / sums[..., np.newaxis]
```

Now, in order to take into account potential zero-sum-ness of some lines, we set one line of the data to 0:

```
X[0, 0, :] = 0

sums = X.sum(-1)

nnz = sums != 0
Y = np.zeros_like(X)
Y[nnz, :] = X[nnz, :] / sums[nnz, np.newaxis]
```

You will observe that `Y.sum(axis=-1)` has the entry 0 in coordinate (0,0) reflecting the zero-ness of the corresponding line.

EDIT: Application to the concrete example

```
X = np.array(array([[[ 0.34      ,  0.66],
                     [ 0.75      ,  0.25]],
                    [[ 0.        ,  0.  ],
                     [ 1.        ,  0.  ]]]))

sums = X.sum(-1)
nnz = sums != 0
Y = np.zeros_like(X)
Y[nnz, :] = X[nnz, :] / sums[nnz, np.newaxis]
```

yields `Y == X` (because along the last axis the sum is already one or zero.)

Comment: Note: This is summing on the rightmost (last) axis. It is slightly easier to sum over the leftmost (zeroth) axis. Anything in between can be brought back to either one of these cases using `np.rollaxis`.

Comment: Here you change the initial data by zeroing: a couple of issues here. First, I would not like to change any data not to lose it, and second, this operation still seems to rely upon the fact that `m=2`

Comment: No, it works on arbitrarily dimensioned data, the sum is on the last axis. It can be on any axis, as mentioned in my previous comment. I do not change the initial data. It is still in `X`. I explicitly create a new array `Y = np.zeros_like(X)` to avoid this issue.

Comment: (If you are referring to my second code block: Yes, I am zeroing a line in X in order to have data compliant with your requirements. However, it doesn't change in the sequel. See third code block: Nothing is done to `X`, it stays the same.)

Comment: Indeed, I was referring to the first line of the second block - didn't realize you just assure there is zero data in the randomly generated matrix. Let me check your code in action.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help!